# negative lookaround regex

Tags: php, regex

i have the following string

```
.proxy.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   0   COOKIE%253BCartID%253B%252F%253Bwww.proxy.com   1914104745%253B
```

and the following regex expression

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\%]{14,15}
```

i want to only match 1914104745%253B but it is picking up COOKIE%253BID, i tried to do negative assertion like this

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\%]{14,15}[?!COOKIE]
```

but that does not work

can anyone help with this regex expression?

Comment: is that string  you want to match have fix lenghth?

Comment: Do the string you want to catch always start with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just anchor to the end of the string with `[a-zA-Z0-9%]{14,15}$`

```
$str=".proxy.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   0   COOKIE%253BCartID%253B%252F%253Bwww.proxy.com   1914104745%253B";
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9%]{14,15}$/',$str,$match); 
echo $match[0];

>>> 1914104745%253B
```

If the part of the string you want to match is strictly formatted you could use something such as `\d{10}%\d{3}[A-Z]$` and you can drop the `$` if the match won't always be at the end of the string, either way only `1914104745%253B` will be matched in your example.

Note: `%` doesn't needed escaping.

Comment: how do i keep the the length assertion of this ? {14,15}

Comment: Not difference as you had it `[a-zA-Z0-9%]{14,15}$` just the `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(?<=\s)[\w%]{14,15}(?:(?=\s)|$)
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?339r3)

Comment: The string aren't fixed length `{14,15}`.

Answer (score 0):

Lookaheads use round brackets, not square ones. But I don't think a look ahead on its own will help here:

```
(?!COOKIE)[a-zA-Z0-9\%]{14,15}
```

Would prevent it matching `COOKIE%253BCart` but then it will simply match `OOKIE%253BCartI` instead. Anchoring the match at the end of the line using a trailing `$` is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to get the last string of non-whitespace characters on the line?  Then use this

```
(\S+)$
```

You could also use `preg_split` to split on whitespace and taken the last element of the array it returns.